# How to generate a mesh in Unreal Engine 4 from binary data from a 3d file like .fbx in runtime with C++?

Tags: c++, 3d, unreal-engine4

My goal is to download the contents of a 3d file from a server and then generate a mesh with that data. I haven't made any progress apart from some research into the topic. I am also a ue4 begginer but i am at home with c++.

Comment: would be useful to share what you have tried so far.

Comment: I basically did some research and nothing more. Don't even know where to start. I'll add that information to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate meshes in runtime you can use Epic's ProceduralMeshComponent or 3rd party project [RuntimeMeshComponent](https://github.com/TriAxis-Games/RuntimeMeshComponent)